# Google Analytics on Third-Party Code

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

We have a client who uses a third-party to capture leads and provide quotes and estimates to its potential customers. We want to see if there is a way to track this form in Google Analytics using goals. The third-party only provides the following code:

```
<div publickey="0768027fa9f00da0ddd0fd1486ea0f59" data-border="0" data-bordercolor="9b90b2" data-backgroundcolor="ebebeb" data-fontcolor="555555" data-buttoncolor="66ff66" data-title="REQUEST A QUOTE" data-country="US" data-orientation="l" id="moverbaselead" ></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//lead.moverbase.com/js/mblead.js"></script>
```

When the code is rendered, it produces an iframe. When a visitor fills out the form, it uses Ajax to produce a Thank you message, so I can’t do an exact match URL.

I’m not savy enough to figure out how add goal tracking to this code, if it’s possible at all. I’d appreciate any help, and perhaps help others out as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the form and the thank you page live inside an iframe in a page/domain that you have no control over then you can't track it.

You would have to install some code inside the iframe, and if you don't control it then it's not feasible.